# Using a string in a file name

Tags: c++, string, file, filenames

Error: *expression must have integral or unscoped enum type*
I get this error for this code: `outFile.open(".\\DB\\" + nm + ".conf");` I tried multiple things to solve this but none worked.

Comment: what is `nm`? Is the error really on this line?

Comment: nm is a constant character

Comment: That wont work. It needs to be a std::string for + to work

Comment: I've did that and the error was solved but when compiling I get this error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'

Comment: Maybe your compiler is too old or set in a pre c++11 standard. It needs c++11 to support a std::string in the first parameter.